# Search Tab keeps disappearing even if I enable it in Ribbon customisation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I'm using Outlook 365 and the search bar is in the top bar of the Window. When you click it, the search tab appears on the Ribbon. This tab auto-disappears from the ribbon after searching. I have checked in the Ribbon customisation menu and it is shown... if I turn it off and on then when I click OK I see it appear very briefly in the ribbon before disappearing again.

Is this just how Outlook works now or can I force it to always be there?

Comment: Just checking in to see if my information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using Outlook 365 and the search bar is in the top bar of the
> Window. When you click it, the search tab appears on the Ribbon. This
> tab auto-disappears from the ribbon after searching.

This is normal behavior for Outlook and the Search Icon on the Ribbon bar.

Two things:

**(1) The Ribbon adjusts the icons it displays automatically.** That is how Outlook was designed. You can reduce the number of unused icons if you wish. This allows other icons to stay without moving around or disappearing. I do this.

Right click in the Ribbon, choose Customize and in the dialogue box that comes up, you can add and remove icons to suit how you work.

**(2) In the same Customize Ribbon dialogue box, left side,** default is Popular Commands, and you can change that to All Commands.  Search is in the All Commands list.

You can try adding the Search Icon. The Outlook Search bar and Icon are a programmed part of Outlook, *so I am not certain this will work.*

As I noted, the behavior you see is normal for Outlook 365 fully updated.

[image: Outlook Ribbon Customization]

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we can add the Search tab in Customize Ribbon. For specific steps, please refer to:

1.**File**>**Options**>**Customize Ribbon**.

2.Under **Choose commands from**, please choose **Tool Tabs**. And under **Customize Classic Ribbon**, please choose **MainTabs**.

[image]

3.Then choose "**+Search**" >  **Add>>**, you will see the **Search(Custom)** tab is added on the right.

[image]

4.Then click **OK**.

In this way, Search tab will be displayed on the top without clicking search bar. Hope to help you!

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mr. Boy, is my reply helpful to you? If so, would you mind mark it as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.